# I can import just first ten items with importxml in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import titles from a website with IMPORTXML function in google sheet but it is import just the first 10 from list, but what i need is to import all titles list

this is my formula:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://erej.org/category/%d9%82%d8%b3%d9%85-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%b9%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%af%d8%a7%d8%aa/%d8%a8%d8%a7%d8%a8-%d8%a7%d9%84%d8%b7%d9%87%d8%a7%d8%b1%d8%a9/","//html//h2")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon checking on the url you have provided, what you are trying to pull is webpage that is dynamically created, specifically, a **javascipt-rendered website** which is a **limitation** of `importxml function()`:[Limitations of IMPORTXML](https://nodatanobusiness.com/blog/a-user-friendly-alternative-to-importxml/#:%7E:text=The%20biggest%20limitations%20to%20IMPORTXML,every%20change%20to%20the%20Sheet.) that means, technically, you can only pull those titles that are already shown, thus, you can only get the 10 titles.

> **Javascript-rendered websites are not supported:** this automatically
> excludes a large amount of websites, as it is common for popular and
> large websites to be rendered in Javascript.

To confirm if the contents are dynamically added, you may checkout **@Ruben's answer here:** [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun/115665#115665)

> ### **Content added dynamically**
>
> To check if the content is added
> dynamically, using Chrome,
>
> 1. Open the URL of the source data.
> 2. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open Chrome Developer Tools
> 3. Press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the >Command Menu.
> 4. Start typing `javascript`, select **Disable JavaScript**, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the command. JavaScript is now disabled.
>
> JavaScript will remain disabled
> in this tab so long as you have DevTools open.
>
> Reload the page to see if the content that you want to import is
> shown, if it's shown it could be imported by using Google Sheets
> built-in functions, otherwise it's not possible but might be possible
> by using other means for doing web scraping.

Another way to disable it is `through web browsing settings:`

1. Go to settings, Find `Privacy and Security`.
2. Click `Site Settings`
3. Go to `Content` Section
4. Click `Javascript` and tick `Don't allow sites to use Javascript`
5. Reload webpage

*Note: I am not affiliated with the website/reference, I just found it through research.*