# ImportHTML table but values are missing

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, google-sheets-formula

I use `IMPORTHTML` function to import a table "LIVE METALS PRICES" on [MetalsDaily](https://www.metalsdaily.com).

This is the table I try to import.

[image]

Below is the result on Google Sheets. Everything works well except the values are show up as expected. Appreciate your advice.

[image]

Comment: It happens because the prices are dynamically loaded from a backend API.  When `IMPORTHTML` fetches the page, the table is indeed empty.  To get the data, you will have to reverse-engineer their API and fetch directly from there.

Comment: TQ @dataful.tech Mind to explain more about reverse engineer API? Can it be achieved with Google Apps Script? If not, can you propose a solution?

Comment: The website pulls data from this url `https://www.metalsdaily.com/__dta/pd.ashx` (POST request). You can see the website in the browser without logging in, usually it means that you can query that url directly and parse the result.  However, there is some kind of validation on the backend side.  Often it is just certain set of request parameters. Once "reverse engineered", the request should be successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a limitation of `IMPORTHTML()`, it is not able to pull content that is dynamically rendered via Javascript.

---

###### To confirm if it is Javascript-rendered you may try the following:

> 1. Open the URL of the source data.
> 2. Press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open Chrome Developer Tools
> 3. Press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the >Command Menu.
> 4. Start typing `javascript`, select **Disable JavaScript**, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to run the command. JavaScript is now disabled.
>
> JavaScript will remain disabled
> in this tab so long as you have DevTools open.
>
> Reload the page to see if the content that you want to import is
> shown, if it's shown it could be imported by using Google Sheets
> built-in functions, otherwise it's not possible but might be possible
> by using other means for doing web scraping.
>
> Another way to disable it is `through web browsing settings:`
>
> 1. Go to settings, Find `Privacy and Security`.
> 2. Click `Site Settings`
> 3. Go to `Content` Section
> 4. Click `Javascript` and tick `Don't allow sites to use Javascript`
> 5. Reload webpage

I have verified that the content from the site you are trying to pull is Javascript rendered. See following result after disabling the Javascript.
[image]

###### Result:

[image]

##### References:

- [I can import just first ten items with importxml in google sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76919092/i-can-import-just-first-ten-items-with-importxml-in-google-sheet/76920062#76920062)
- [How to know if Google Sheets IMPORTDATA, IMPORTFEED, IMPORTHTML or IMPORTXML functions are able to get data from a resource hosted on a website?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/115664/how-to-know-if-google-sheets-importdata-importfeed-importhtml-or-importxml-fun/115665#115665)

Comment: Thanks @Logan, it is helpful. Mind to share if there is alternative to scrap the data?

Comment: @OngK.S you can try using Google Apps Script. 
[Google Sheets Web Scraping: A Simple Guide for Extracting Data from Websites in 2023](https://scrape-it.cloud/blog/google-sheets-web-scraping)

Comment: thanks @Logan. I will try Google Apps Script.

Comment: You're welcome @OngK.S! Feel free to accept my answer (by clicking the accept button on the left) so that other members in the community (who may have the same concerns as you) may know refer to this post or you may also upvote if this helps. If you have concern on the apps script part you may post it as another question which is totally focused on that. Thanks